# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift

I have to install PodFile for AlmoFire.
Please give me proper solution of this bug.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /Users/rigel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DFE42BCD-C617-4C9F-9EF3-EEC02635013C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3391D0FF-76B5-44EF-BD05-4759635C467B/AppName.app/AppName
  Reason: image not found
```

Error Image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VjPW.png

This image for Embed Pods Frameworks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTX9I.png

This image for the imported framework
https://i.stack.imgur.com/89kyB.png

Please give me proper solution.

Thank You

Comment: Check Runpath Search Paths in build settings. is it empty ?

Comment: clean / uninstall from device and retry

Comment: @sharadchauhan Runpath Search Paths is not Empty.

Comment: @CZ54 I Done All the things.
Uninstall Simulator.
Deep Clean Project
Delete Derive Data also

Comment: @Parth make sure this is there in Runpath : @executable_path/Frameworks

Comment: @sharadchauhan It is same like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Open Pod file using command

open -a Xcode Poffile

Add Alamofire using pod 'Alamofire'

install pod using command

pod install

Try by adding here see image

[image]

Comment: Manish Please check my second image.